# Drupal Hook_Menu access wildcard

Tags: drupal, menu, hook

i want to get my wildcart but i cant...

my link in Hook_menu :

```
$items = array();


$items['tv8/channel/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Detail channel Tv8',
    'description' => 'Détails d\'une chaîne Tv8',
    'page callback' => 'tv8_program_channel_detail',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
```

my link is defined like that :

```
"<a href='?q=tv8/channel/test'>" . $channel->name ."</a>" ,
```

and here my  callback function :

```
   function tv8_program_channel_detail($id)
{
    $content_admin_panel = $id.
                            "<div class='body'>" .
                                "<ul class='admin-list'>" .
                                    "<li>" .

                                        "<div class='description'>" .

                                        "</div>" .
                                    "</li>" .
                                    "<li>" .

                                        "<div class='description'>" .

                                        "</div>" .
                                    "</li>" .
                                "</ul>" .
                            "</div>";

    $content = array
    (
        'content' => array
        (
            '#markup' => t($content_admin_panel),
            '#prefix' => '<div class="admin-panel">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        ),
    );

    return $content;
}
```

But id return "channel" and not "test".

I think i'm doing wrong but cant found anything in drupal doc.

Comment: FYI, there's a Drupal SE site that might get you better answers... http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page arguments you need change it to **array(2)**. Based on your path array(0) load 'tv8', array(1) load 'channel' and array(2) load argument %. So code will be as follow:

```
$items['tv8/channel/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Detail channel Tv8',
    'description' => 'Détails d\'une chaîne Tv8',
    'page callback' => 'tv8_program_channel_detail',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Also better for link use php function l():

```
<?php print l($channel->name, 'tv8/channel/test'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$items['tv8/channel/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Detail channel Tv8',
    'description' => 'Détails d\'une chaîne Tv8',
    'page callback' => 'tv8_program_channel_detail',
    'load arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```